# What is wrong with my code here (Python, Lists, Strings)?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, split

I'm iterating through a list "a" with length x, where if column 1 has more than one line break, I want to copy that entire row x and replicate it but has column 1 with a unique value.

For example, if I have a row and column 1 contains values (A, B, C), I want to copy all the other data, and have it only contain 1 value in column 1.

```
steps = []
temp = a[x]
if a[x][1].count('\n') == 0:
    steps.append(temp)

else:
    split = a[x][1].split('\n')
    count = a[x][1].count('\n')+1
    for b in range(0, count):
        temp[1] = split[b]
        steps.append(temp)
```

**Intended result of list "steps":**

```
xxx, A, yyy, zzz
xxx, B, yyy, zzz
xxx, C, yyy, zzz
```

**Actual result:**

```
xxx, C, yyy, zzz
xxx, C, yyy, zzz
xxx, C, yyy, zzz
```

Comment: What is `x` in this code? Also, what's the input data for that result example?

Comment: x is the row number, the data is from an excel file which I read into Python via Pandas.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. If `x = len(a)` as you say, then `a[x]` should be giving you a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero Where does OP say that `x = len(a)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very hard to understand because you didn't define `a` or `x`.

Nevertheless, the problem is almost certainly that you modify and append the same `temp` dict each time. You need to copy it:

```
    new_temp = temp.copy()
    new_temp[1] = split[b]
    steps.append(new_temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Python lists are mutable adn you are always modifying the same list.

When you do:

`steps.append(temp)`

In each iteration, you are adding the same list (`temp`) to the result list `steps`.
As in each iteration you are modifying the second element of the list `temp` when doing

`temp[1] = split[b]`

The result `steps`list, will have each of it's elements (as they are all the same element) modified.

Ilustrated:

Step 1

```
b = 0
split[b] = A
temp[1] = split[b] -> temp = "xxx, A, yyy, zzz"
steps = [temp] === ["xxx, A, yyy, zzz"]
```

Step 2

```
b = 1
split[b] = B
temp[1] = split[b] -> temp = "xxx, B, yyy, zzz"
steps = [temp, temp] === ["xxx, B, yyy, zzz", "xxx, B, yyy, zzz"]
```

Step 3

```
b = 2
split[b] = C
temp[1] = split[b] -> temp = "xxx, C, yyy, zzz"
steps = [temp, temp, temp] === ["xxx, C, yyy, zzz", "xxx, C, yyy, zzz", "xxx, C, yyy, zzz"]
```